# TypeError: Cannot read property '_rawValidators' of null after Ng build

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-build

I am new to angular. I am dynamically rendering some fields into my reactive form. Everything works great when I am using `ng serve` with a mock request (i.e. rendering happens properly, no error in the console.log). As soon as I build the project with `ng build` and use a proper backend, I get the error for each field I am rendering dynamically:

```
main.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_rawValidators' of null
```

I couldn't find any background on this error. I would love to hear your thoughts.

#### more background

```
// these fields change with selection
this.datafields = [{
              dfId: 48,
              dfName: "Phone",
              dfType: "text",
              dfOptions: null,
              dfValue: ""
              },
              {
              dfId: 49,
              dfName: "Eval",
              dfType: "select",
              dfOptions: ["","Remote","Live"],
              df_value: "",
              }]
```

typescript rendering in `ngOnInit` (tried `ngAfterViewInit` with no improvement)

```
dfGroup = new FormGroup({})
...
...

 this.eyeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      focus: ['', Validators.required],
 datafields: this.formBuilder.array([])
})

...
...

  if (this.datafields != null || this.datafields != undefined) {
  this.datafields.forEach((x:any) => {
          this.dfGroup.setControl(x.dfName, new FormControl(x.dfValue));
        });
  this.getDataFields.push(this.dfGroup);
  }
```

and HTML looks like the following:

```
 <div [formGroup]="dfGroup">
   <div class="row pt-2" *ngFor="let field of datafields; let i=index">
      <div class="col-4 d-flex align-items-center 13required">
         {{field.dfName}}&nbsp;
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
         <mat-form-field *ngIf="field.dfType == 'text'" appearance="outline">
            <input
            matInput
            [type]="field.dfType"
            [formControlName]="field.dfName"
            required
            />
         </mat-form-field>
         <mat-form-field
            *ngIf="field.dfType == 'select'"
            appearance="outline"
            >
            <mat-select [formControlName]="field.dfName" placeholder="">
               <mat-option
               [value]="option"
               *ngFor="let option of field.dfOptions"
               >
               {{ option }}
               </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
         </mat-form-field>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "main.js:1" is printed in your error stack: try to deactivate [the optimization option](https://angular.io/cli/build#options) when building/serving your app, it will give you more insights. About your error, I had the same, but the situation was a bit different: I was passing a form control as an input (i.e.: `<app-foo [formControl]="formControl" />`) and it was failing because `formControl` seemed to be also used as a directive. Aliasing the input solved my issue (i.e.: `<app-foo [fwdFormControl]="formControl" />`)

Answer (score 24):

I ran in to this situation when I was mocking out my template and typo'd my formControlName attribute.

```
<mycomponent formControlName="bogusfieldSpelledWrong" ...>
```

Why Angular showed it as this error likely has something to do with how the component was initializing/changing the form.

Comment: Adding to this, it appears that this happens when you try to add a form field in the template with a formControlName that doesn't exist in your FormGroup.

Comment: @AaronAverett I've experienced this as well, AND...  i would love to know how we can detect (or avoid) this in future.  This error is very elusive and easy to commit.

Answer (score 9):

This is caused by malforming the form in the view.

It was caused by misordering `formArrayName`, the loop and `formGroupName`

The form (controller)

```
form = <FormGroup>this.fb.group({
    hops: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({...}),
        ...
    ])
});
```

The view (mistake)

```
<li class="asset" *ngFor="let control of hops.controls; let i = index;">
    <div formArrayName="hops">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
```

The view (corrected)

```
<div formArrayName="hops">
    <li class="asset" *ngFor="let control of hops.controls; let i = index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
```

Answer (score 6):

it must be about formControlName. check out your form control names in ts file and html file.
for nested groups you can use formGroupName, then use formControlName.

```js
this.yourForm = this.fb.group({
    name: [''],
    contact: this.fb.group({
      address: ['']
    }) 
})
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="yourForm">
  <input type="text" formControlName="name" />
  <div formGroupName="contact">
    <input type="text" formControlName="address" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using a formControlName in Html which wasn’t added to the form in typescript file

Answer (score 1):

In our application, we had a minifier that renamed class variable names (in this case, the name of form controls) as an optimisation. This made the issue only appear in our production environments (optimisations weren't performed during local development).

The solution was to directly reference the control instance instead of using a string, so that the variable referenced in the angular template was renamed consistently with the class local variable.

Before:

```html
  <div formGroupName="myInputGroup">
    <div formControlName="myInput">...</div>
  </div>
```

After:

```html
  <div [formGroup]="myInputGroup">
    <div [formControl]="myInputGroup.controls.myInput">...</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

another reason for this issue is when you forget to assign `formGroup`

wrong:

```
export class MyComponent{
 formGroup: FormGroup;
 ...
}
```

correct:

```
export class MyComponent{
 formGroup = new FormGroup({...});
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I had an input field that did **not** **have** `formControlName=""` inside of it

instead of

```
<input>...</input>
```

do:

```
<input formControlName="myInput"> ...</input>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is resolved by adding **formcontrolname** value.
Type error gives you null because it didn't find value from your Component.

In your Html file **formcontrolname** must be the same as FormGroup value.

For example:

```
<formControlName = 'username'>

this.formGroupName = this.formBuilder.group({
    username: ["", [Validators.required]],
    }) 
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//html page properties

    formControlName="drugReproductive"

//ts file attributes
   

     this.drugTypeTwo = new FormControl(0);
        this.drugTypeThree = new FormControl(0);
        this.drugTypeFour = new FormControl(0);
        this.drugTypeFive = new FormControl(0);

    this.drugWithCanisterForm = this.fb.group({
          drugAntineoplastic:this.drugAntineoplastic,
          drugNonAntineoplastic:this.drugNonAntineoplastic,
          drugReproductive:this.drugReproductive,
          drugTypeOne:this.drugTypeOne,
          drugTypeTwo:this.drugTypeTwo,
          drugTypeThree:this.drugTypeThree,
          drugTypeFour:this.drugTypeFour,
          drugTypeFive:this.drugTypeFive,
          configuration: this.configuration,
          deviceId:this.deviceId,
          deviceTypeId: this.deviceTypeId,
          isOtcExcluded: this.isOtcExcluded,
          isScheduleExcluded: this.isScheduleExcluded,
          isUnitOfUsageExcluded: this.isUnitOfUsageExcluded,
          unitOfUsageValue: this.unitOfUsageValue,
          canisterQuantity: this.canisterQuantity,
          canisterSize: this.canisterSize,
          searchText: this.searchText,
          scheduleExcludedValue: this.scheduleExcludedValue,
          nioshValue:this.nioshValue,
          superCellNo:this.superCellNo,
          lockingCellNo:this.lockingCellNo,
          superLockingCellNo:this.superLockingCellNo,
          isNioshExcluded:this.isNioshExcluded
        });
```

In my case this problem arised, because i didn't bind the formControllName attributes in my form object